# Authorize a non-admin developer in Xcode / Mac OS

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, privileges, dscl

I use a standard user account for my daily tasks on Mac OS. Since upgrading to Snow Leopard I am asked to do the following when a program is run from within Xcode:

"Type the name and password of a user in the 'Developer Tools' group to allow Developer Tools Access to make changes"

While I know the admin username/password, this is annoying (though only required once per login).

The developer tools access is asking for rights to "system.privilege.taskport.debug" from application gdb-i386-apple-darwin.

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You need to add your `macOS` user name to the `_developer` group.  See the posts in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2654321) for more information.  The following command should do the trick:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me for about 10 minutes, and then for some reason it started asking for my username/password again. I tried typing it into Terminal again, but it no longer responds.

Comment: This works for me and I have no issue until now. Noted just for reference.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me until I added `-u <name-of-account-with-root-access>` to the options.  So my full command was `dscl -u <root-account> . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <my-account>`

Comment: You should consider using 'merge' instead of 'append' if you add this line to a continuous integration script. Merge will not add it if it already exists. See 'man dscl' for more details.

Comment: You have to add `-u <root-account>` to make it work, please add this in the answer as second option if first didn't work.

Comment: This worked to add me to the group but only after I used @Kheldar suggestion to su into a root account first.

Comment: Simply using `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable` worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725547/9636

Answer (score 25):

Finally, I was able to get rid of it using `DevToolsSecurity -enable` on Terminal.
Thanks to [@joar_at_work](https://twitter.com/#!/joar_at_work)!

**FYI**: I'm on Xcode 4.3, and pressed the **disable** button when it launched for the first time, don't ask why, just assume my dog made me do it :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning DevToolsSecurity. I had no idea such a tool exists. I had the opposite problem, I wanted do disable it again and thanks to this tool I finally was able to :) Just replaced `-enable` with `-disable` and that works as expected!

Comment: This command seems to have no effect at all. Xcode 4.3 still requires authentication from someone on the _developer group regardless whether -enable or -disable is used.

Comment: Just to clarify, this step is, at least in some cases, _in addition_ to adding the user to the _developer group with `dscl -u <root-account> . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <my-account>`

Comment: Does not seem to work on macOS "El Capitan" with XCode 7.3. @Kheldar's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ dseditgroup -o edit -u <adminusername> -t user -a <developerusername> _developer
```

Comment: In my humble opinion, this answer really could benefit from a bit more explaining on what it does. It's not that I don't like typing sudo rm -rf / on my system, but you get my point. :D

Answer (score 8):

You should add yourself to the Developer Tools group.  The general syntax for adding a user to a group in OS X is as follows:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/<group> GroupMembership <username>
```

I believe the name for the DevTools group is `_developer`.

Answer (score 4):

Ned Deily's solution works perfectly fine, provided your user is allowed to `sudo`.

If he's not, you can `su` to an admin account, then use his `dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership $user`, where $user is the username.

*However, I mistakenly thought it did not because I wrongly typed in the user's name in the command and it silently fails.*

Therefore, after entering this command, you should proof-check it.
This will check if $user is in $group, where the variables represent respectively the user name and the group name.

```
dsmemberutil checkmembership -U $user -G $group
```

This command will either print the message `user is not a member of the group` or `user is a member of the group`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! The commands that worked for OS X Mavericks were `dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership username `and `dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "username goes here" -G "group goes here"`

Answer (score 2):

**Answer suggested by @Stacy Simpson:**

We are struggling with the issue described in these threads and none of the resolutions seem to work:

- [Stop "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue" alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg)
- [Authorize a non-admin developer in Xcode / Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837889/authorize-a-non-admin-developer-in-xcode-mac-os)

As I'm new to SO, I cannot post in either thread. (The first one is actually closed and I disagree with the localization reasoning...)

Anyway, we created a work-around using AppleScript that folks may be interested in. The script below should be executed asynchronously prior to launching your automated test:

```
osascript <script name> <password> &
```

Here is the script:

```
on run argv
    # Delay for 10 seconds as this script runs asynchronously to the automation process and is kicked off first.
    delay 10

    # Inspect all running processes
    tell application "System Events"
        set ProcessList to name of every process
        # Determine if authentication is being requested
        if "SecurityAgent" is in ProcessList then
            # Bring this dialogue to the front
            tell application "SecurityAgent" to activate
            # Enter provided password
            keystroke item 1 of argv
            keystroke return
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

Probably not very secure, but it's the best work-around we've come up with to allow tests to run without requiring user intervention.

Hopefully, I can get enough points to post the answer; or, someone can unprotect this question. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Snow Leopard and this one didn't quite work for me. But the following procedure worked:

1. First added another account with admin privileges by ticking "Allow user to administer this computer" under Accounts, for example an account with username **test**
2. Logged into the **test** account
3. Launched Xcode, compiled and ran my iPhone project. All ok, no errors were thrown related to permissions
4. Logged out of the **test** account
5. Logged in with the another account having admin privileges
6. Took away the admin priviliges from the **test** account by removing the tick from "Allow user to administer this computer" under Accounts
7. Logged back into the **test** account
8. Deleted the iPhone project directory and again checked out from the repository (in my case svn)
9. Launched Xcode, compiled and ran the project. I didn't get any errors and the App ran well in the iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I found the suggestion in the following thread helped:

[Stop "developer tools access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue" alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg)

It suggested running the following command in the **Terminal** application:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better solution from
[Mac OS X wants to use system keychain when compiling the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204320/mac-os-x-wants-to-use-system-keychain-when-compiling-the-project)

> 1. Open Keychain Access.
> 2. In the top-left corner, unlock the keychain (if it is locked).
> 3. Choose the System keychain from the top-left corner.
> 4. Find your distribution certificate and click the disclosure triangle.
> 5. Double-click ‘Private key’ under your distribution certificate.
> 6. In the popup, go to the Access Control tab.
> 7. Select ‘Allow all applications to access this item’.
> 8. Save the changes.
> 9. Close all windows.
> 10. Run the application.

Answer (score 0):

After you run:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/_developer GroupMembership <username>
```

per the answer above, you may **still** get prompted to enter in your own password:

*We need authorization from an admin user to run the debugger.
This will only happen once per login session.*

What it really means is any *_developer* groupmember user so just your non-admin user/password will work here but to get rid of it completely (no prompts after a reboot) you'll also need to run:

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

*(running it with sudo as an admin user/as root will make it so you can do it remotely without a gui password prompt)*