# Running app on ipad asks for System username and password again and again

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipad

When I am running my application on my device, it asks for system username and password again and again. Previously, I was running on iphone, it asked for first time only.

[image: Snapshot for asking username and password]

Comment: maybe some keys for your provision profiles placed in System keychain?  In this case you should move them to another keychain

Comment: in application Utilites/Keychain Access , move them to the "login" keychain

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738298/xcode-asking-username-password-everytime-i-compile-to-device?rq=1

Comment: Just checkin @PavelKatunin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some keys for your provision profiles placed in System keychain? 
In this case you should move them to another keychain.
In application Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access , move them to the "login" keychain.

Answer (score 1):

You should move them to another keychain. In application Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access , move them to the "login" keychain.
Enter your credentials, you problem will be resolved.