# How to run phonegap app in iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm new in Xcode. I'm having Xcode 4.6 and Mac OS 10.7. I have setup the phonegap environment to my Xcode and can create my phonegap app successfully.

My problem is, when I start to run my app into simulator it's showing the following error:

> Developer Tools Access needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue. Type the name and password of a user in the "Developer Tools" group to allow this.

and also showing the username & password textbox.

I have tried to give apple develoer credential and also system credential but not getting any solution.

Comment: Its asking for system credentials 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738298/xcode-asking-username-password-everytime-i-compile-to-device

Comment: This might help (Try kenster's answer)        

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132826/stop-developer-tools-access-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process-for-debugg