# When I First time open my ios Simulator, It ask for password

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, keychain

Every time after rebooting my system when I start my ios simulator for first time it ask for system password. After providing it first time it never ask. How to resolve it so that it never ask for password?

Because of it every time when I start my simulator for first time it take too much time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check where your certificates installed from keychain.

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah Yes I have checked it according to [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738298/xcode-asking-username-password-everytime-i-compile-to-device)  and it is installed in login section. Also it ask password only for first time only not always.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetely there is no way to prevent this. You will just have to always put in your password.

However you can try to check with the workgroup manager from the server admin tools to ensure your user is member of the "Developer Documentation" and "Developer Tools" group.