# How to run xcodebuild to build xcode project without any input

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I want to build the xcode project with xcodebuild in command line, I can run it successfully, but when I run the command line, it always ask me inputting the username and password, I don't wanner to do with this step, is there any way make it run automatically without inputting username and password, or is there options of xcodebuild can let me skip this step?

Comment: Something is broken then; why would it need your username/password?

Comment: Post the command you are using.

Comment: I enter the directory of the xcode project and run command: "xcodebuild", all other options as default, after the command run for a while, there is dialog popup and ask me input the username and password, it shows "Mac OS X wants to make changes. Type an administrator's name and passworkd to allow this. Mac OS X wants to use the "System" keychain."

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068566/xcode-keeps-asking-for-password-to-use-the-system-keychain