# Codesign wants to access key "access" in your keychain, I put in my login password but keeps asking me

Tags: xcode, keychain, codesign

I'm trying to learn to load apps on my iPhone from Xcode.  When I do I keep getting "Codesign wants to access key "access" in your keychain,  I put I my login password but it keeps popping up over and over.  I've tried my computer login so many times, apple account password, and many others.

[image]

Comment: You have to select `Always Allow` when you finished input password

Comment: Actually, @VictorJohn, the problem is that the dialog opens and won't accept any passwords. I have the same issue, and it's weird as hell.

Comment: In this case, what you should do is to clean those caches, Xcode and Keychain and system caches respectively.

Comment: @VictorJohn would you mind tell us how?

Comment: @Green First, Reset Dialog Warning in Xcode preference -> General. Second, delete all caches in cache directory -> `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. Third, restart your mac. Forth, open Xcode, run a project, always allow the Xcode accesses KeyChain.

Comment: @VictorJohn, Didn't help. It still stops and asks for password. And I don't know password.

Comment: @Green The password can't be skipped.

Comment: Here are other suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068566/xcode-keeps-asking-for-password-to-use-the-system-keychain. Going to KeyChain, moving the certificate to Login and also allowing apps to access it, plus deleting Derived Data and resetting the computer worked for me.

Comment: You have to be persistent. I had to enter my password and click "Always Allow" maybe ten times before it stopped prompting me.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work unless I clicked [Always Allow].  It is crazy that [Allow] does not work and [Always Allow] does.

Comment: the correct solution is indeed to enter your pasword (the one you use to login on your Mac), then hit 'always allow', and keep repeating that until the dialog closes ... I had to repeat it about 10 times! Looks like the dialog respawns a few times, so you have the impression that nothing happens ... but it does, just keep repeating!

Comment: Same for me. Hit Always Allow and just do over and over again until it moves on. The dialog does not do anything so you think nothing happened but if you enter the password enough times, it may work. At least it did for me.

Comment: I used the password that i `login to my mac with` and hit `Always Allow`, which worked for me.

Comment: ALSO... if you hit Allow multiple times then you will have dialogs "stacked" on top of each other. You need to move them away until you find the first dialog without a **** password. Enter your mac login password and hit "always allow" then continue to do that with any dialog that does not have a password. Once you've done that start doing the same for any of the dialogs you moved out of the way by re-entering your password and hitting "always allow" ... this is a joke but you need to do it or you will be hitting always allow forever.

Answer (score 787):

Had the same issue. It was fixed after I entered my mac user password and hit **Always Allow**.

Comment: For me *Allow* did not work, only *Always allow*, so be sure to click that one.

Comment: shouldnt this be reported to Apple as a bug?

Comment: I had to enter it multiple times for this to work!! I thought that the password was wrong and tried what not ... So annoying!! I lost hours because of this.

Comment: I used to solve it with the "Alway Allow" button but either Mac OS X Mojave or Xcode 10 removed that button. any ideas?

Comment: OMG, you are a genius. tried to fix this shit for 6 hours. Your solution worked for me. Thanks god

Comment: You have to be persistent, I had to follow this step 10 times or so before it stopped prompting me.

Comment: Looks that xcode ask the password at every internal step. "Always allow" avoids reenter each time.

Comment: I had the same issue. But when I put the Mac login password and hit "Always Allow", the problem solved. Thanks for your info.

Comment: this should be marked as the solution

Comment: if you don't have any 'always allow' button then leaving the password empty seems to work

Comment: This worked like magic, the mac user password and the always allow did the trick!

Answer (score 130):

Solve this problem by doing this.

1. Enter your **Mac Login Password and Choose "Always Allow"**
2. One or **More dialogs opened and positioned in the same dialog, repeat step 1** until all dialogs closed. (So you thought your
   password wrong but repeat "Always Allow" with your Mac login
   password tricky part :) )

Hope it will work.

Comment: Mac login password doesn't work. I may only work if they are the same. If a user has different mac usr password, it won't work

Comment: I was convinced the successive dialogs meant I entered the wrong password...thank you!

Comment: By entering correct password and choosing "Always Allow" worked.

Comment: Thanks! Normally user tries another password when dialog popups again. We must be patient and repeat the same password until we see "Always Allow". I think button "Always Allow" should be showed from the first time. It is misleading. Apple platform is sometimes very stupid.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to enter my password and click "Always Allow" about 10 times!! I recommend being persistent.

Comment: @Jason I got you beat. Mine was at least 15. I was just about to give up hope until I read your comment. Cheers

Comment: @GreatBigBore, I'm glad my comment helped! "Wash, rinse, repeat. Always repeat." - Homer Simpson

Comment: @User9527 Yes, especially the password related things, they need to learn more from google. Every time asking password is irritating.

Comment: What a stupid bug/feature. This got me too. They should at least differentiate between each of the repeating prompts that appear.

Comment: In my case, even after entering password and pressing "always allow"/ "allow" dialog won't pop. I am stuck

Comment: There is no "always allow" button. If there was, I could have figured it out myself.

Answer (score 70):

I pressed *Deny* by mistake and I was stuck, no way to code sign any Pods.

This is how I solved the problem:

- Open the keychain
- look for the key `com.apple.gs.xcode.auth.com.apple.account.AppleIDAuthentication.token`
- open it
- click on the *Access Control* tab
- at the bottom there's *Always allow access for these applications:* -> add Xcode in the list
- Don't forget to press `Save Changes`

[image]

Comment: I love this. Before, maybe xcode 8 and below, I had been trying to script allowing access to something like  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign , but since xcode9 that path does not exist. Any tool would be inside the parent .app so this is very good. :cross-fingers: for no more issues!

Comment: How do I open the keychain?

Comment: @Antinous the Keychain is an app. You can find in under Applications/Utilities -> Keychain Access

Comment: worked! "Save Changes" didn't do anything, however in answer below toggling the login lock helped

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I still had half a dozen dialogues around, but when I entered my login keyword, this time they went away, and the project built without further problems. Xcode 10, macOS 10.13.6. Still not fixed.

Comment: Wasn't saving, had to restart the Mac to be able to save.

Comment: It's the best answer.

Comment: On macOS 11.3, it's not possible to make any modifications under access control anymore :(

Comment: @LyteFM Reboot your Mac may make it works.

Answer (score 40):

2019: I had to enter the password like 40 times... must be a bug... but it worked

Comment: Insane that this is the solution lol I can't believe it worked for me

Comment: I confirm, just enter your mac login password press allow always and keep doing it until it's okay, don't give up, you should be ok after a few tries (10-40). Definitely a bug.

Comment: 2020: continuous integration machine is not happy with this

Comment: I try 3 times, but them instead of hit enter or give to allow, I click on allow always and it result, , anyway the real solution for this is only to logon on xcode, this problem comes with every update than you make on xcode

Comment: 2021 on 11.3: Over 50 confirmations required, no option to „always allow” or to adjust the permission via the keychain. But yeah in the end it worked...

Comment: 30 dec 2021 almost 30 prompts. and it worked, there is no always allow

Comment: Completely insane, pressed like 40 times and suddenly it worked. (4 Nov 2022 using command line `flutter run`)

Comment: 2023/03 confirmed. Worked for me after 12 attempts. It allows to paste your password, so don't type it every time.

Comment: April of 2023 on 14.3 M1 chip doing an Archive of a React Native project. Had to enter the password at least 50 times. Lost track after that. No always allow button. I even quit a few times assuming I was stuck in an endless loop and then finally found this answer and just plugged away for a long time. I wouldn't be surprised if this lined up with the number of cocoapods install for the project (95).

Comment: Note, if you are not getting an "Always Allow" button, moving the certificate that was used for the provision profile(s) from your System keychain to the login keychain might do the trick.

Answer (score 30):

I encountered this running a brand new project. Neither the Allow or Always Allow button seemed to work, however it wasn't giving me the 'incorrect password' shaking feedback. What was happening was that there were multiple dialog boxes all in the same position, so as I entered a password and clicked Allow nothing changed visually. I ended up having at least 3 dialogs all stacked up on each other, which I only discovered when I tried dragging the dialog. Entering passwords into each of them let my project finish building.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, saw it because the shadow around the dialog was a lot more visible than normal. When uploading the app I did get another 2 dialogs. It seems okay now. Oh Xcode...

Comment: What password does it need?

Comment: @Green The answers by Bharathi Devarasu (the answer currently below this answer)  and Anton Eregin (answer above) describe what password this dialog is asking for. However, in some cases the keychain password may not be the same as your mac user's password. If you've forgotten your keychain password, you can reset it. Perhaps try the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928239/how-do-i-get-myself-out-of-apple-developer-id-certificate-mess

Comment: You are awesome stranger.

Answer (score 23):

Enter your **login password**, and select **always allow**, to avoid typing in your password multiple times.

[image: codesign access]

Comment: pressing always allow doesn't work. It ends up asking again and again anyway.

Comment: "Only" 8 times with the current SDK. Used to be 5.

Comment: this button is missing for me

Answer (score 20):

I clicked the "Deny" button, and the keychain was off.

I locked the keychain:

[image]

And then I entered the login keychain again.

Comment: What is _login keychain_? How can I get one?

Comment: OPen the app called Keychain Access

Answer (score 20):

**Following worked for me!**

1. open keychain-management on your Mac
2. select "login" on the left pane
3. look for the key which is causing this issue. Mine was iOS Developer...
4. double-click the key and select "Allow access to all programs" in the access column

Restart Xcode and try to build again. It will ask you again but with the additional option to "Always allow. Enter your macOS user password as password and press "Always allow".

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: If it not works, try to reboot your Mac.

Answer (score 15):

Enter the password you use to open you Mac session and click on "Always allow" until all alerts are closed. The other buttons do not work...

Comment: this doesn't work anymore, I've tried doing it more than 200 times and never goes, also there is no "allways allow" anymore i'm in Monterrey 12.6

Answer (score 9):

The same dialog asking for the KeyChain password has 3 buttons. Most likely the wanted password is that for logging in to your Mac. If you press "Allow" it only works for some tiny aspect and will ask again, which is very puzzling. You need to press "Always Allow". The verification team at Apple is very weak, they need some 'normal' developers in the design team for the chain of events to get an app in the app store. Normal developers have very sketchy ideas about KeyChains and Certificates and Profiles.

Comment: I was trying my developer account password, did not know then that it was mac machine password. Thanks for the added info.

Answer (score 8):

I faced this issue recently where I was been asked to enter the Username and Password in the POP UP and where I entered it for like almost **105**+ times as in the POP UP there was no "**Always Trust**" option available. The option in the POP UP were "**Deny**" & "**Allow**" only.

So thought to add my thoughts here as none of the above worked for me. Though the solution was a combination of above answers but no one mentioned to add the developer certificate to keychain under the section

**System** and **Login**

I had my certificate added under the **System** option but not under the **Login** option in the keychain on the Left hadn't side of Keychain Access.

After doing this the issue was not there and I live happily thereafter.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding. Cheer's.

Comment: Thank you! I only had the certificate under *system*, not *login*, which meant that codesign never had the "Always allow" option. Adding the certificate to both *login* and *system* workd!

Answer (score 5):

Okay Guys, after literally 2,5 hours of trying to fix that error I managed to find a solution that worked on my two Mac Machines.
These are the steps I did:

1. Open Xcode -> Preferences
2. Go to the Accounts Tab
3. Click the button on the bottom right telling 'Manage certificates'
4. Look for the name of the certificate
5. Open the keychain manager
6. Select in the menu the Sign-In tab
7. Do a right-click and then delete on the certificate that was named in the Xcode settings page before
8. Go back into Xcode and see Xcode creating a new certificate(The window will be empty for a couple of seconds and then there will a new certificate lighten up.
9. Rerun your app

I hope that could help you guys. It helped me a lot! :)

Liam

Comment: for me it is not regenerating the certificate again, any clues.

Comment: I downloaded and added certificates manually into KeyChain, which seemed bad.
Let XCode manages and download certificates for you.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I didn't have the 3 buttons described in the other answers ("Allow", "Always Allow", "Deny"). I only had an "OK" button.

I tried entering the following passwords:

- Login password, the one I use to login to my Mac.
- Apple ID, the one I use to authorize App Store purchases and login to my iCloud.
- Apple Developer ID, the one I use to login to App Store Connect.

But none worked.

What **did** work, strangely, was ***leaving the password text field empty***.

Comment: Yep, leaving the password empty and clicking OK helped

Comment: WTF?! I had the same situation, only the "OK" button and leaving it empty worked. One of the wildest bugs ever.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem. I had more than one Xcode window open, closing all other open windows leaving only the current one open solved the problem for me.

Comment: Even after 15 years of experience with Apple, their incompetence and stupidity still astounds me.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this is a bug, but don't worry you can continue your build without any problem. Like all others I am sharing my experience.

The dialog will pop up again and again, and I thought that I maybe forgot the keychain password.

what you have to do is **enter the Mac login password** and press *Always allow*.

if nothing is happening, check the dialog by dragging it with mouse, and move the dialog. you will find same dialog underneath.

try separating all the dialog through out the screen and find the dialog that is working. (ie, maybe only only dialog will accept the password and close. yeah, it may reopen new dialogs anyway. but never mind.)

Continue the password entering and pressing always allow until it give up.

I entered the password around **20 - 30 time** I guess. and it worked pretty well.

*now thinking that if I press always allow on the first time, maybe it will not come again.*

Answer (score 4):

Deny all popups until you have only one popup left (also you have to deny the popups in the reverse orders they were opened)

When only one is left enter user password and always allow.

Can't believe this is happening in 2023.

Answer (score 3):

As of August 31,  2018.

```
Resolving:
 1.  Search Keychain Access
 2.  [KEYCHAIN] Login | [CATEGORY] Passwords
 3.  Look for you email address and double click. <it might not be necessary but just try this>
 4. [ACCESS CONTROL] choose  "allow all application to access this item".
 5. Rebuild to your phone.  If you have error choose a virtual device and build (to reset the build objects).  Then choose to rebuild to your phone again.
```

Comment: Where's this from?

Comment: HIGH SIERRA Version |

(1) search in spotlight: "keychain access"
(2) on the left side Top "Keychains" click Login
(3) on the left side Lower "Category" click Passwords
(4)then proceed to step 3. (above instruction)."

Answer (score 3):

In my particular case, the dialog box did not have the *Always Allow*, *Allow* or *Deny* options, so I wasn't able to use the above solutions. I had to go to my Keychain Access app, choose the certificate, go to "Access Control" and add Xcode in the apps to *Always Allow* access. After that, the dialog showed the *Always Allow* button, which I could use successfully.

[image: Access Control Dialog Box]

Comment: There is no option to do so within the latest macOs.

Answer (score 3):

For me there was no password of the system, there was no password at all, just allow with blank password and it works

Answer (score 1):

For me, I realized one of the dialogs was opened in another workspace. Once I discovered that and input my password there it went through.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to enter the incorrect password. After that, when entereing the correct password, new dialogs started to open in different places of the workspace. I had to enter the correct password about 20 times hitting Always allow. Which helped!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was caps lock. and it seems it may ask you a couple of times to input your password or you will have to enter a password once and press always allow.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the certificate in the keychain access and change the access permission if you want to avoid entering password at all, else select **Always allow** and it will prompt probably 4-5 times and it will be done.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the problem while running the carthage script in the build phase. (Xcode 9)
I get that dialog for each and every framework I had added plus the app itself. You can see a very dark shadow growing.
I could bypass it by entering the password every time and hitting "Always Allow".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: while building iOS release for Flutter project, was asked for keychain password, entered Apple ID password for developer account, no luck.
Finally succeeded by entering password for computer I was using (which was an on-line mac server).
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me XCode had expired my login...XCode-Preferences - saw it had logged me out, loged back in. Only came up with this solution by chance thanks to a related post here that took me to preferences in XCode !

Answer (score 0):

dialogs open on each other some of them should confirm first , if you enter password many times and it dosen't work just drag a dialog and see if there is any other dialogs under it and confirm them. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, for me it opened up several boxes, so I had to pay attentions that when I clicked always allow for one box, another box, flickered. So had to add all the passwords and clicks in an ordered fashion according to the mac.
then I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For those that have had no luck with the provided answers:

Try to first turn off any app that might be changing your mouse behaviour (like "Mos", that smooths scrolling) and any bluetooth mice you have connected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is best solution:

1-)revoke all certificate in your apple developer account

2-)log off your developer account inside xcode

3-)relogin with your developer account

4-)re-create certifiactes...

It will work like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The popular answers are outdated.

**Update 2022**:  Just press Enter. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639924/xcode-codesign-wants-to-use-the-apple-development-keychain-password-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and for me the "**Always Allow**" option was not coming so I had to enter the username and password again and again and after entering for almost 150+ times, I checked in case the **p12** is there or not earlier which I added also but it got removed somehow and I added the p12 again and boom I got the "Always Allow" option also and in a single try it worked.
For me this worked like a charm. Try doing this. This error of pop up will go.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it keeps popping up is because you installed the certificate in the system location, move it to the login location and it will ask you once and enter your password and click on always allow.

Answer (score 0):

2024: Did work only after rebooting the system. So do not try to enter the password 40 times. just reboot.