# My code won't run on a iPhone "Failed with Exit code 1" error message

Tags: swift, xcode

(Sorry First Time App Maker)
When I go to run an app on my test phone That I have built in Xcode, it pops up with a keychain login and when I put my password in it disappears and reappears within half a second.

When I click deny it makes the build fail and won't let me run the app on my test phone.

It outputs this when I click on the error message.

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice\ Roller.app (in target: Dice Roller)
    cd /Users/drewmcclennon/Desktop/Dice\ Roller
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
    export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
    export SDKROOT="/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk"
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign DB0FAA9830CEE1E5C6727C0B81A477B85FB56EB5 --scan-executable /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice\ Roller.app/Dice\ Roller --scan-folder /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice\ Roller.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice\ Roller.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Volumes/GoFlex\ Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice\ Roller.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice\ Roller.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Volumes/GoFlex\ Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Dice\ Roller.build/Debug-iphoneos/Dice\ Roller.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
/Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib -r -o /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
Copying /Volumes/GoFlex Backup/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib to /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign DB0FAA9830CEE1E5C6727C0B81A477B85FB56EB5 --verbose /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib: code object is not signed at all

/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib: code object is not signed at all

/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib: code object is not signed at all

/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
Codesigning /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
Codesigning /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
Codesigning /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign DB0FAA9830CEE1E5C6727C0B81A477B85FB56EB5 --verbose /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign DB0FAA9830CEE1E5C6727C0B81A477B85FB56EB5 --verbose /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign DB0FAA9830CEE1E5C6727C0B81A477B85FB56EB5 --verbose /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign DB0FAA9830CEE1E5C6727C0B81A477B85FB56EB5 --verbose /Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dice_Roller-edqodyccejvkgravqgvpztiumxjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Dice Roller.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried making a new keychain but that didn't work.
I have also tried restarting the MacBook.
Any help will be appreciated.
Many Thanks 
Drew

Comment: Tried deleting the derived data folder? (*/Users/drewmcclennon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I just have and that didn't help. the keychain still pops up and disappears and reappears within 0.5 seconds when given the correct passcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound completely stupid (and arrogant, which is not the intention).

Have you tried entering your password again?

From time to time I see this error as well when deploying to an actual device and it is usually because there are multiple password dialogs stacked *on top of each other*. Yes it may appear as if it is the same dialog, but it is actually different instances.

This answer has some suggestions as well (and is hinting at the same issue): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50657877/4063602

If you get tired of typing your password over and over, type it into a text editor, cut it from there and paste it...at some point you will get past it.

I don't have an answer to why it behaves as it does, but the above usually does the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will try now!

Comment: Whoever and wherever you are please know that you have made my day and I hope that something good will happen to you in return. I am veers grateful for your help and wish you a good day!

Comment: Thanks @DrewMcClennon you are too kind :) glad it worked. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.