# Xcode codesign wants to use the "Apple Development" keychain password wrong

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, apple-developer

I built an app with flutter and now I want to deploy it to my iPhone via Xcode. But when I deploy with debug configuration, I do not access my app on my phone when disconnecting it from my mac. So I searched and saw that I should build in Release configuration but when I do so I get a pop-up like that [image]

I entered my only user password but it declines. I searched and saw that pressing always allow was working fine but in my case there is not this option. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

There is actually no password. You just have to hit enter.

Comment: Can you, please, mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: this is crazy. It works.

Comment: This is insanity  by definition. Putting in the password does not work. You have to press Enter.

Answer (score 2):

It required actually your system login password and from the options click on

> "Allow always"

[Apple Developer Community](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92336)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following things happened;

I have previously defined a custom certificate for this developer account. And this certificate was visible under custom in the sidebar in the certificate manager. I completely removed it, then turned the automatic signing button on and off again. Afterwards, everything went as expected.