# xCode asks my system login and password after each changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS X wants to use system keychain when compiling the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204320/mac-os-x-wants-to-use-system-keychain-when-compiling-the-project)

If I make any changes in my project and then press 'Run', xCode asks  my system login and password after each changes.

How to turn it off?

[image]

Comment: The answer is to enable developer mode on Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the .p12 key in the keychain -> AccessControl -> (Select not to ask password there)