# Mac OSX asking for keychain access when building MonoDevelop iOS App

Tags: ios, macos, monodevelop, osx-mountain-lion, keychain

When building projects in MonoDevelop on the Mac, I get the message "MAC OS X wants to make changes.Type an administrator's name and password to allow this. MAC OSX wants to use system keychain."

I found the post [Mac OS X wants to use system keychain when compiling the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204320/mac-os-x-wants-to-use-system-keychain-when-compiling-the-project)
but this doesn't quite answer my problem. The profiles I installed were done via XCode and are my current/valid profiles on the Provisioning Profile so I assume these are Ok - XCode reports they're valid.

I've moved my dev environment from a Macbook (where compiling apps worked fine, without this error) to another Mac and this has started appearing.  If I enter my username/password it compiles and works.

Any ideas why this is happening?

(One thing which I wonder may be causing a problem... when I ORIGINALLY setup the dev env on my Macbook, I exported/backed up my certificate as Jonny WIlson.p12.  On my new Mac however, I couldn't import this. I tried re-exporting it and importing it again, this too failed.  Is this INITIAL certificate (used to generate your development/distribution certificated in the Provisioning Profile) a vital part of getting this working? I'm asking this because I read in a forum once you have  your Apple certs, this key is no longer needed?  Is this correct?)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I went to Keychain Access, selected "system" in "Keychains" (top left). 
Then for each item: right click, "Get Info", "Access Control" and added Xcode in "Always allow acces by these applications:" list.

(I'm not using MonoDevelop, but guess the problem reason is similar)

Answer (score 1):

Hat tip: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25092

Since El Capitan, you can no longer click on "Allow" or "Always allow" programmatically.

This includes from Screen Sharing!

Supposedly you can just  plug in a mouse to your headless Mac and click "Always Allow". This didn't work by me until I closed all active Screen Sharing sessions.

Then I plugged in a monitor, mouse & keyboard, clicked "Alway Allow" and life is good; until i have to deal with a new certificate.

Comment: If Apple had given a message ,after clicking allow it would be just too easy to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for El Capitan:

1. export certificate to .p12
2. open terminal
3. run: `security import <pathToP12> -k <keychain_name>.keychain -t priv -f pkcs12 -A`

You will be asked to enter keychain password and that's all.