# Mac Code Signing: Bypass the Keychain Access private key prompt from Terminal

Tags: macos, security, osx-mountain-lion, keychain

I'm working on an app in Mac OS X Mountain Lion that needs to access the private key of some of my certificates within the Keychain Access. Since this app is going to run on a server, I need to avoid the pop up dialog that requires the user to allow the app to access the private key:

[image: Pop up dialog]

I know that by clicking "Always Allow" the dialog won't popup anymore for that private key, the problem is that I will be working with different keys.

Thanks in advance,

Mikywan.

Comment: For El Capitan, you will need the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33650464/1285846

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way I found to solve this is by setting up the Private Key in the Keychain Access to "Allow all applications to access this item".

[image: Private Key Properties: Access Control]

You can configure this from the Terminal when you import the certificate into your Keychain.

**Import command**: `import inputfile [-k keychain] [-t type] [-f format] [-w] [-P passphrase] [options...]`

**To set the access control to "Allow all applications to access this item", just add the flag "-A"**.

You can check always [Apple's manual on *security*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also specify single applications allowed to use the key instead of all applications by using the -T flag on `security import`. For example: security import my_input_file -T /usr/bin/codesign . You can use multiple -T flags to specify multiple programs. This information can also be found on Apple's manual on security, linked in your answer.

Comment: On a new El Capitan server I just set up; I was only able to grant access by re-importing using the command line tool and adding the -A option.

Comment: Looks to be out of date and not working on Monterey anymore :(