# iOS Adhoc export fail

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using xcode 8 and i'm not able to create .ipa file via Archive > Export ( as Adhoc ) Why this happen?

> 2016-10-16 14:17:01 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error
>   Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "ipatool failed with an
>   exception: #toolsPath' for
>   nil:NilClass>
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:781:inrawLoadCommands'
>       /Applicati…" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=ipatool failed with an exception: #toolsPath' for
>   nil:NilClass>
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:781:inrawLoadCommands'
>       /Applicati…}

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but check the 'Access Control' of the private keys in keychain access. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733764/mac-code-signing-bypass-the-keychain-access-private-key-prompt-from-terminal

Comment: @BrienPafford Thank you for your reply. I solved this via restarting XCODE. after restart it's worked correctly.