# Xcode 7 with El Capitan unable to sign binary for export - can't press "allow" button

Tags: xcode, macos, keychain, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm running into an issue where a Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan is unable to codesign a binary for adhoc distribution. The issue is bizarre:

- I've transferred a distribution cert on this mac
- XCode asks me if it can use a private key to sign the ipa
- Clicking on "allow" or "always allow" does nothing, the password box does not shake for wrong password.

As a result, I'm unable to export an IPA (this private key has never been used before on this Mac).

**How do I fix "unable to click allow or always allow" issue with Xcode7 / El Capitan?**

Attempting to set the distribution cert to "always allow" fails within keychain assistant as well:
[image]

Comment: same problem here. When I try to run first aid - check it says it can't unlock the keychain (which already has the unlocked icon)

Comment: @miga - see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33650464/1285846

Answer (score 9):

El Capitan does not allow software to click the "Allow" or "Always Allow" buttons for security reasons. If you are running software that intercepts mouse events such as **`MagicPrefs`**, this may register as a software click. Try disabling any software that reads mouse events, or using a standard USB mouse.

I found the answer here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25092
and here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7305746

Comment: This helped me in figuring out what the problem was!!! I was accessing the build box through OS X "Screenshare" and trying to code sign with a new key, would not be allowed, unless I did it with a physical mouse/trackpad attached to the machine :(

Comment: My issue was `MagicPrefs`, so quitting it worked. But holy crap, Apple, how about *some* sort of message or warning!

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete solution but I was able to work around this by booting into Safe Mode and building from there. While in Safe Mode I also added the Xcode application to the keychain item and now it doesn't ask for permission anymore.

Comment: awesome that worked! I could change the "always ask" propertie of the private key (keychain - right click on the private key - information) to "always allow" and now I can compile again

Comment: I tracked my issue to having `MagicPrefs` installed like mentioned in BFeher's comment. Temporarily disabling `MagicPrefs` allows me to click the button without having to boot into Safe Mode.