# App keep asking for password to use 'Local Items' keychain

Tags: ios, swing, keychain

I am trying to sign an app. But App keep asking for password to use keyhcain. I am facing this issue only for one app. following popup is showing again and again:

[image: popup]

I cannot understand what is the actual problem. Please help if any one know the answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Certificate on Keychain which is under "System" which is password protected,so every time you build app it will ask for credential.

try below steps:

1. Go to keychain
2. Select system at left side
3. Select your certificate from list and click dropdown
4. Select access control
5. Select allow all applications to access this item
6. Save changes

From answers here: [Mac OS X wants to use system keychain when compiling the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204320/mac-os-x-wants-to-use-system-keychain-when-compiling-the-project)